# Addition of days with hours , minutes , second in vba

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, time, vba

I have database with Column 'StartDate' as '01/01/2018 10:00' and 'EndDate' as '01/01/2018 11:25'. I have multiple recordset based on certain criteria.

I would like to calculate the difference between 2nd 'StartDate' with 1st 'EndDate' and than sum them all the difference.

I have put the sample database here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cc5ba

I am thinking that using query it is not possible so i have started doing this using vba.

using the help of function elapsedtime from below link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/calculate-elapsed-time

I am able to get the difference as string for first row as 145:30:00 in "hour:minute:second"

Problem No:1
how can i change this string as date-time format .

I have tried 'Format(CDate(Caclute_time), "hh:mm:ss")' but it gives me an eroor Type mismatch.

Problem No:2

How can i add the time 
for eg. 104:40:00 (hh:mm:ss) + 20:21:00 (hh:mm:ss) which give me results as 125:01:00

Answer (score 0):

You should always leave the time as a Date, until you're going to format it. Since you didn't, you're getting yourself in a bit of a mess.

We need 2 functions, one to cast a date to the hh:mm:ss format, and one to cast it back to a date.

```
Public Function DateToHHMMSS(theDate As Date) As String
    DateToHHMMSS = Int(CSng(theDate * 24)) & ":" & Format(theDate, "nn:ss")
End Function

Public Function HHMMSSToDate(theString As String) As Date
    Dim dateArr As Variant
    dateArr = Split(theString, ":")
    If UBound(dateArr) = 2 Then
        HHMMSSToDate = TimeSerial(dateArr(0), dateArr(1), dateArr(2))
    End If
End Function
```

With these functions, you can easily add these dates together, for example:

```
DateToHHMMSS(HHMMSSToDate("104:40:00") + HHMMSSToDate("20:21:00"))
```

And to cast a string to a date, simply use:

```
DateToHHMMSS("104:40:00")
```

Comment: your comment makes sense to me and now i am converting the difference of dates in second and then make a sum of all the seconds, In the last i am converting those seconds in to days, hours:minutes:seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just sum the time difference:

```
Select Sum([DateEnde] - [DateStart])
From MTTR
```

and then format it using a function like this:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```

like this:

```
Select 
    *,
    Nz((Select Top 1 T.DateStart 
    From MTTR As T 
    Where T.LFD_NR > MTTR.LFD_NR
    Order By LFD_NR Desc), [DateEnde]) - DateEnde As TimeDiff
From 
    MTTR
```

Save this as, say, MTTR_Diff.

Then:

```
Select 
    FormatHourMinute(Sum([TimeDiff))
From 
    MTTR_Diff
```

Comment: function FormatHourMinute in my case will not going to help me because I would like to get the difference between 2nd 'StartDate' with 1st 'EndDate' and than sum them all. But still you function is going to work for to caluclate the difference between the two dates.

Comment: I am getting an error while running the query on sqlfiddle. something is missing or messed up.

Comment: sql fiddle is for mysql only. Use the query designer in Access.